# Click in finder vs "open -a" on command line

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript

I have a file type (.mxl -- compressed MusicXML) which if I double click in Finder opens properly in my .mxl reader (Finale 2014.app) but which if I call "open file.mxl" or "open -a /Applications/Finale\ 2014.app file.mxl" does not get parsed by Finale. My question isn't specific to this program, but more general: is there a general way to invoke the behavior on the command line that is identical to the behavior of double clicking in Finder?

I would have thought that "open file.mxl" would be it, but the difference in behavior in this program suggests that it's not the same.

(before marking as duplicate: I have searched the archives and it seems like there are a lot of questions about cases where the user knows exactly what he or she wants to do via the command line but can't duplicate the behavior in Finder. This opposite problem doesn't seem to have a solution).

**Edited:** Have found a partial solution as: `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Users/Cuthbert/file.mxl"'`

Comment: Didn't you notice that Terminal can only find apps or files with known or specified paths?!? . . . This is general behaviour and not "partial", whereas Finder can identify files by extension and start their default application.